# How to achieve the content load on scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, loading, fading

Am wondering on how i can achieve this "fading" effect when the content (on-scroll) loads. I have seen this on multiple websites yet couldn't find a specific tutorial on this specific topic.

Demo: http://demo.lollum.com/suburbs/

Comment: I only know how to achieve enlightenment, does that help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique is called "lazy loading" + some fade-in animation. On the web it is commonly applied to images. 
The website in question is a WordPress website. 
WordPress has a bunch of lazy-loading plugins, like http://wordpress.org/plugins/bj-lazy-load/

Answer (score 0):

You sound like you may want to check out a Parallax Scrolling Plugin ... here is a quick list I found from googling http://medleyweb.com/web-dev/15-useful-jquery-parallax-plugins-and-tutorials/

Comment: Nope, the OP sounds like someone who has made no effort in figuring anything out at all.

Comment: @adeneo Well maybe he has never heard of "Parallax Scrolling" before... who know lol but I think that should set him on the right track.

Comment: @adeneo I am sorry but what you're saying seems so stupid to me, i have only asked for a link or a name, which i already got from Vital in a previous answer.

Comment: @Banning, thanks for the link but it is not Parallax which i am aware of, apparently it's Lazy Loading, thanks anyway.